# Is there an operator similar to modelica's homotopy() in ModelingToolkit(MTK)?

Tags: julia, modeling, modelica

Is there an operator similar to modelica's  `homotopy()` in ModelingToolkit(MTK)?

Or how can I achieve this method?

Anything about help would be appreciated！

Comment: This is not implemented right now. You can track the progress in the issue https://github.com/SciML/ModelingToolkit.jl/issues/1385